# How to assign Stream object to function

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I am trying to use the StarkSoft.Ftp library, i have it all working but want to store the retrieved file to a Stream object for use in my application, i am quite new to streams so was hoping for some advice? Here is the function

Retrieves a remote file from the FTP server and writes the data to a local stream object specfied in the outStream parameter.

public void GetFile(
    string remotePath,
    Stream outStream,
    bool restart
)

Here is my code but the data isnt put into stream object i specify

Stream stream0 = new MemoryStream();
ftp.GetFile(col[0].Name, stream0, true);

Any pointers?

Tony

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the stream's position to the beginning in order to read it:

```
stream0.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```